# is there any way to make a two dimensional database on vb 2010?

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, n-dimensional

Im preparing a program for my teacher friends using vb 2010 express. They keep records about their students. I prepared a database that contains a table named "Mystudents". It has columns like "studentId , Name, Surname, etc.." . My problem starts here. Each student attends lots of lessons during a year. I must keep "which lessons they attended", "when they attended", "which topic done in the lessons" for each students. for example

Id: 104
Name : Jason
Surname : Black
Class : 10A
on 12.04.2011 he attended math lesson and they do trigonomtry
on 14.04.2011 he attended physics lesson and they do gravity
.......
.......

Id: 105
Name : Marry
Surname : Steward
Class : 11B
on 02.04.2011 she attended math lesson and they do trigonomtry
on 14.04.2011 he attended physics lesson and they do gravity
.......
........

i mean i have a list of data for each record of databese. Please halp me..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a relational database design, you would typically include a "relation table" to keep track of this:

```
   --------------
   |  Student   |
   --------------
         | 1
         |      
         | 0..*
--------------------
| Students_Lessons |
--------------------
         | 0..*
         |
         | 1
   --------------
   |   Lesson   |
   --------------
```

The `Student` table have `StudentID` as primary key, the `Lesson` table has `LessonID` as primary key, and the `Students_Lessons` table contains the two columns `StudentID` and `LessonID` which will link students to lessons.

As you see in the database design above, each record in the `Student` table can be linked to zero or more records in the `Students_Lessons` table. The same goes for the `Lesson` table; each record can be linked to zero or more records in the `Students_Lessons` table. However, each record in the `Students_Lessons` table must be linked to exactly one record in `Student`, and one record in `Lesson`.

If each student may attend each lesson once only, you can extend the `Students_Lessons` table with additional columns for any other information that you require, otherwise it's probably better to extend the data model with additional tables for storing more information.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you're looking for a 1-N and M-N relationship.

Best suggestion would be you should learn more about database design. You can start googing what's a 1-N and M-N relationship in relational databases.

You're looking to support that in VB, but this is out of .NET scope but it's a database design thing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE student
        (
        id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        firstName NVARCHAR(200),
        lastName NVARCHAR(200),
        )

CREATE TABLE subject
        (
        id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        subjectName NVARCHAR(200)
        )

CREATE TABLE class
        (
        id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        subjectId INT NOT NULL
                FOREIGN KEY
                REFERENCES subject,
        classDate DATE,
        topic NVARCHAR(200)
        )

CREATE TABLE student_class
        (
        studentId INT NOT NULL
                FOREIGN KEY
                REFERENCES student,
        classId INT NOT NULL
                FOREIGN KEY
                REFERENCES class,
        PRIMARY KEY (studentId, classId)
        )
```

Comment: Absolutely: he's an student and I don't like this kind of answers. It's just a "I want N" and you gave the solution without letting him learn how to think the right solution. In instance, you don't know exactly which database technology is using. You're assuming is SQL Server, and, by the way, this question should be answered in terms of teaching database relationships :)

Comment: @Matias: do I get you right: you think the solution is correct but downvoting it because of the fact that it, in your opinion, does not educate the op sufficiently?

Comment: @Quassnoi You know it's not the right solution since you don't know database technology behind the question. And yes, I downvote it, because an answer shouldn't be "hey, this is the source code!". You didn't explain why this is the solution, and you know question author's has low database design knowledge, so, do you think this is a solution for him? Maybe he doesn't understand it! What a solution haha :D

Comment: @Matías: do I get you right: you think the author is not able to ask for clarification if he does not understand something, and "you should learn" and "start googling" would be a better answer than a source code with a comment form below it?

Comment: @Quassnoi. Yes. I think it's the way because he's an student, I gave him some hints. Stackoverflow isn't a learning platform, but quick or long answers for concrete problems, is it? For that reason, I believe it's better to give hints than a SQL Server T-SQL source code.

Comment: @Matías: so when a student comes to Stack Overflow to learn, you think that the best thing to educate them would be sending them out of Stack Overflow with an advice to "learn" or "google"?

Comment: @Matias - I agree with Quassnoi. I don't see any point in tiptoeing around homework questions and giving cryptic clues as to the answer. It is the OP's responsibility to manage their own learning and yes they should make sure they understand the answer given, how it applies to their own question and seek any additional clarification necessary but if they choose not to that is not the fault of the answerer.

Comment: You both and others can agree with whatever, this is freedom of mind. You can argue "googling" is not a good answer too, and that's because you didn't read my answer at all. I gave hints, then reading documentation about my hints, he may get a clue about question was asked because a lack of knowledge. What do you think?

Comment: @Matías: None argues with you here, people just ask questions. It's your right to give any answers you like, and downvote any answers you don't like, correct or not.

Comment: @Quassnoi I find this discussion absolutely useless. Keep giving source code instead of answers if you feel this is the right way of doing things! If I told you "I don't like" is because I wanted to say it more friendly! Also, you'd need to accept criticism. Criticism is always subjective, isn't it? :)

Comment: @Matías: there is no discussion here. I'm asking you questions, you answer them. I'm not giving advices like "learn", "google", "keep doing this" and "go accept that" because this is not polite in my opinion, neither to the posters, nor to the peers.

Comment: Aside from anything else this DDL is a poor example. There is no explanation or obvious reason why student names, subject and class topics are nullable. The class table doesn't have any keys. There are several syntax errors from standard SQL (use of FOREIGN KEY and missing commas). It uses the reserved word NAME. It includes invented attributes not mentioned or implied in the questions.

Comment: @dportas: you forgot to add that there can be names longer than `200` characters and the statements are not semicolon delimited, but you're right, the requires polishing. And what about invented attributes?

Comment: @Quassnoi That's the point, for me throwing a piece of source code for a conceptual question is the easy way. "keep doing this" isn't "polite". Double-check my answer: I start my answer with "If I'm not wrong" and I add "I suggest you...". Maybe you're reading wrong, because the point is he asked such question because he doesn't know about relationships (n-dimensional database? what's that?). When I find someone with poor knwoledge in some area, I give him/her hints. Sometimes hints are a solid answer.

Comment: @Matías: sorry, why are you telling me all this? I didn't downvote you.

Comment: @Quassnoi I'm just trying to give you a reason of my downvote in your answer. I like discussing point of views.

Comment: @Matías: are you trying to convince me my answer is bad?

Answer (score 0):

What is the question?

Try to write down all the properties/entities you'd like to store in your database. Based on that, you can perform some normalization to achieve the optimal database structure.

For example: a student's got an id, name and surname. Those properties belong together in a students table.

Further; a student will follow lessons. But this is not a 1:1 relationship. So in the first place you'll get a table 'lessons' where all lessons are defined, after that you'll get a StudentsLessons table where the link between lessons and the students attended is created.

Comment: You are right. "StudentsLessons table" is useful, but it will have so many data during a year. (there are about 300 students and each will get about 100 lessons during year. so there will be 30000 records in StudentsLessons table) it will be hard to make a search in the future. So i want my program creates a new table for each student that user added. If it is not possible i will do your advice..(StudentsLessons table)

Comment: But a database is optimized for tables with a lot of records. You can speed up searching by using indexes on the important fields (most of the time PK/FK's). Your idea of a separate table is possible, but I'd not advise it because of maintenance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 3 tables.

```
students

student_id    student name .. etc ..
1             jane doe
2             jack dee


lessons

lesson_id    lesson_name   .. etc..
1            gravity 101
2            hard maths
3            hampsters  

student_lessons

student_id    lesson_id
1             1
1             2
1             3
```

Google-ing database design stuff like "normal form", "1 to many", "many to many" and "many to 1" relationships would help you here.